# My prime number checker thinks 15 is a prime number

Tags: python, primes

```
num = int(input("Number: "))
returned = False
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2, (num - 1)):
        if (num%i) > 0 and returned == False:
            returned = True
            print(f"{num} is a prime number")
        elif (num%i) == 0 and returned == False:
            returned == True
            print(f"{num} isn't a prime number")
else:
    print(f"{num} is neither a composite number or a prime number")
```

This code returns that 15 is a prime, and has many other problems, too. I don't understand what the computer is thinking.

{Update}

I updated the code accordingly and now it works fine

```
quit = ''

while quit != "q":
    n = int(input("Enter the number: "))
    is_prime = True
    limit = n - 1
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(2, limit):
            if (n%i) == 0:
                is_prime = False
                print(f"{n} isn't a prime number...")
                break
    if is_prime and n > 1:
        print(f"{n} is a prime number...")
    elif n == 1:
        print("The number is neither a composite or a prime...")
    elif n == 0:
        print("This is not a prime number, this is your exams result.")
    quit = input("(q)uit or (n)o: ")
    if quit == 'n':
        print("continuing")
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No matter what `num` is, you are declaring it prime or not based on whether it is divisible by 2. (Either `num % i > 0` or `num % i == 0` has to be true if `num` and `i` are both non-negative; there is no third option that would allow the `for` loop to continue in a useful manner.)

Comment: If `num %i > 0` (or more usually written `num % i != 0`), then `num` *might* be prime. If `num % i == 0`, then `num` is *not* prime. Only after the loop completes is it possible to confidently assert that `num` *is* prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to review the % operator

```
num = int(input("Number: "))
isPrime = True
if num > 1:
  for i in range(2, (num - 1)):
    if (num%i) == 0:
      isPrime = False
      print(f"{num} isn't a prime number")
      break
  if (isPrime):
    print(f"{num} is a prime number")
else:
  print(f"{num} is neither a composite number or a prime number")
```

Comment: You can use an `else` clause on the `for` loop instead of using a boolean flag to determine if you used `break` or not.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that was an option!

Comment: Thanks bro, your answer helped me the most.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your input number is 15.
Already on the first iteration of your loop (i=2)
Your if statement equals to true since 15%2 = 1 which is greater than 0 therefore you execute `print(f"{num} is a prime number")`

A better implementation would be:

```py
num = int(input("Number: "))
is_prime = True
for n in range(2,int(num**0.5)+1):
    if num%n==0:
        is_prime = False
        print(f"{num} isn't a prime number")
if is_prime:
    print(f"{num} is a prime number")
```

Comment: No, you are printing that num is prime if `num` is divisible by `n`. (Never mind the indentation error and the apparently declaration that num is not prime no matter what else happens.)

Comment: It should be right now the Indentation gut somehow messed up sorry for that.

Comment: Better :) See my comment on the other answer as well.